# Counting holidays in month but not weekends

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to calculate COUNT of holidays in specified month, that are not on weekends. In other words, holidays that fall on Monday-Friday. I can count all holidays in month. Using following formula:

`= COUNTIFS(tblSviatky[Datum];">="&DATE(YEAR(DatumVEvidMesiac);MONTH(DatumVEvidMesiac);1);tblSviatky[Datum];"<="&EOMONTH(DatumVEvidMesiac;0))`

Filtering out the weekends is a problem. I'm trying following:

`COUNTIFS(tblSviatky[Datum];">="&DATE(YEAR(DatumVEvidMesiac);MONTH(DatumVEvidMesiac);1);tblSviatky[Datum];"<="&EOMONTH(DatumVEvidMesiac;0);WEEKDAY(tblSviatky[Datum];1);"<>"&6;WEEKDAY(tblSviatky[Datum];1);"<>"&7)`

Trying to filter weekdays that are 6-Saturday or 7-Sunday.
I somehow fail to see the error. Please help. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Try Networkdays formula to exclude the weekends https://support.office.com/en-us/article/NETWORKDAYS-function-48e717bf-a7a3-495f-969e-5005e3eb18e7

Comment: Just figured it out this way! Thanks anyway.

Comment: btw, the `WEEKDAY(tblSviatky[Datum]; 1)` resolves as **7** for Sat and **1** for Sun, not 6 and 7. For 6 & 7 you would need `WEEKDAY(tblSviatky[Datum]; 2)`.

Comment: Im posting the comment as answer please accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [NETWORKDAYS](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/NETWORKDAYS-function-48e717bf-a7a3-495f-969e-5005e3eb18e7) formula to exclude the weekends then calculate the holidays :)

Comment: although I figured it out myself, i'll accept this answer. Thanks. just cause. :)

Answer (score 1):

I used formula NETWORKDAYS to exclude the weekends. In multiple cells.
First I counted all workdays (mon-fri) then counted all net-workdays (without holidays) and then did the math.